# Adding controls from foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to add controls to a panel from a foreach loop. 
When i press the button i want every element from a array to show as checkbox. This is wordking fine, then i want a numeric updown  behind the checkbox so users can select a value.

The code for creating the checkboxes works just fine, for every item in my array it displays e checkbox. But it only shows 1 NumericUpDown.

Can anybody tell me why it only shows 1 numeric updown, while it shows all of the checkboxes?

Here is my code:

```
private void bierButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int height = 1;
    int padding = 10;
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[10];
    NumericUpDown[] nmr = new NumericUpDown[10];
    orderBox.Clear();
    hideBtn();
    foreach (string bieren in Drinks.bier)
    {
        chk[i] = new CheckBox();
        nmr[i] = new NumericUpDown();
        chk[i].Name = i.ToString();
        chk[i].Text = Drinks.bier[i];
        chk[i].TabIndex = i;
        chk[i].AutoCheck = true;
        chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 0 + padding + height, 200, 22);
        panel1.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
        testPanel.Controls.Add(nmr[i]);
        height += 22;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you're not filling in its Bounds property? Maybe all your NumericUpDown controls are simply displaying on top of each other, all positioned at exactly the same location.

Comment: Not related to your current problem but are you shure that `Drinks.bier` will only have at max 10 items? If I where you I would do `new CheckBox[Drinks.bier.Count]` (or equivalent). **EDIT**: In fact there is no reason to use an array at all in your code, just declare `CheckBox chk = new Checkbox(); NumericUpDown nmr = new NumericUpDown()` right inside the foreach loop (and drop all of the `[i]`'s). **EDIT2:** Also I would use change `Drinks.bier[i]` to `bieren`

Comment: It looks like you only have one (1) **Drinks**, to me.

Comment: Tnx guys, i needed to add and fix my bounds property. It works like a charm now. @ scott Chamberlain, you where right, no array needed. Tnx all for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are not updating the position of your **NumericUpDown** controls.

All of them are there, they are just on top of one another.

Consider this change:

```
private void bierButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int height = 1;
    int padding = 10;
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[10];
    NumericUpDown[] nmr = new NumericUpDown[10];
    orderBox.Clear();
    hideBtn();
    foreach (string bieren in Drinks.bier)
    {
        chk[i] = new CheckBox();
        nmr[i] = new NumericUpDown();
        chk[i].Name = i.ToString();
        chk[i].Text = bieren; // Drinks.bier[i];
        chk[i].TabIndex = i;
        chk[i].AutoCheck = true;
        chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 0 + padding + height, 200, 22);
        // Start New Code
        nmr[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 0 + padding + height, 200, 22);
        // End New Code
        panel1.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
        testPanel.Controls.Add(nmr[i]);
        height += 22;
        i++;
    }
}
```

I also changed one line to `chk[i].Text = bieren;`.

Comment: Of course, the **Bounds** for `nmr[i]` should be whatever you need them to be.